# Not able to install aerospike, getting aerospike failed at step 'node-gyp rebuild'

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install aerospike nodejs module but not able to install it.
Getting below error.

aerospike failed at step 'node-gyp rebuild'
exit status 1

aerospike failed at step 'node-gyp rebuild'
exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
aerospike.target.mk:193: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/aerospike.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/aerospike.node] Error 1
rm binding_gyp_aerospike_client_c_target_Installing_Aerospike_C_Client_dependency.intermediate
make: Leaving directory '/home/kartiknigam/repository/forms/node_modules/aerospike/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/kartiknigam/.nvm/v4.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/kartik/.nvm/v4.5.0/bin/node" "/home/kartik/.nvm/v4.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/kartik/repository/forms/node_modules/aerospike
gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/kartik/.nvm/v4.5.0/bin/node" "/home/kartik/.nvm/v4.5.0/bin/npm" "i" "aerospike"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! aerospike@3.7.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aerospike@3.7.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the aerospike package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs aerospike
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls aerospike
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 6):

First try to install '**node-gyp rebuild**':

```
npm install node-gyp rebuild
```

If the error is still persistent then check for the following dependencies, as Aerospike depends on them:

- libssl-dev
- zlib1g-dev
- libpng-dev

If not installed already, install these packages by:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Comment: npm install node-gyp rebuild was failing for me on WSL2 & Ubuntu 20
I had to do npm install node-gyp rebuild then aerospike installation suceeded

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1207